# Rails Action View Error: route said to be missing when it is not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I have one route in my Rails 4 application that is no longer working which just happen to be one of my most important. It works in my development environment and use to work in my production environment but no longer does. This seems to be the only path which doesn't work anymore. The error looks like:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"profile", :controller=>"business"}):
```

It occurs in my view on this line, which use to work.

```
<%=link_to dba.name, {:controller => 'business', :action => 'profile' },  :id => dba.site_link, :uid => dba.unique_id, :class => "blue-orange-link", :target => "_blank"%>
```

By the way, I've moved the "}" to follow ":uid=>dba.unique_id" as well and that didn't resolve the issue.

I raked my routes and it does display route. It is defined in my routes.rb file.

```
get '/business/profile/:id/:uid'   => 'business#profile'
```

I've tried it with and without the "/" before "business" as well.

I've searched and can't find anything similar to my issue. Typically the answers involved making sure the route was defined, which isn't my problem.

I've reboot my server and application many times. I downloaded my app from my server just to search it to ensure there were no naming conflicts. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED.

Moved the `}` after the parameters in the link and things began working again. It isn't clear why it stopped working and started working again but here is the change.

```
<%=link_to dba.name, {:controller => 'business', :action => 'profile' ,  :id => dba.site_link, :uid => dba.unique_id", :class => "blue-orange-link", :target => "_blank"%>
```